# How to use computed property with getters and setters to trigger commit in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuex, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a computed property: `category` in an input field bound by v-bind like following:

```
  <select name="Category" :value="category">
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="TV">TV</option>
    ...
  </select>
```

and I have getters and setter for this computed property as follows:

```
computed:{
    category: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.category
      },
      set (value) {
        console.log("Value of category changed")
        this.store.commit("SET_CAT", value)
      }
    }
}
```

But when I change input, setter does not get called, How can I achived this, or what other way can be to change state variable directly from HTML input field.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdu9yfhc/2/) is fiddle for this.

Comment: I noticed in your 'set'  function, you have this.store not this.$store.commit... that might also be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked just by change `v-bind` to `v-model` in `select`.

```
<select name="Category" v-model="category">
  <option value="" disabled hidden>Select Product</option>
  ....
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdu9yfhc/4/).

Please post answer if you feel there is still some better way to do it.